# easy way to open modal dialog on secondary monitor?

Tags: java, javafx-2

Consider this:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.SceneBuilder;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ButtonBuilder;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.LabelBuilder;
import javafx.scene.layout.FlowPaneBuilder;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.stage.Modality;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.stage.StageBuilder;

public class DualMonitorProblem extends Application {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

@Override
public void start(final Stage stage) throws Exception {

    Label label = LabelBuilder.create().text("I seem to be lost").build();
    Scene dlgScene = SceneBuilder.create().root(label).build();
    final Stage dlgStage = StageBuilder.create().scene(dlgScene).resizable(false).build();
    dlgStage.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
    dlgStage.initOwner(stage);

    Button btn = ButtonBuilder.create().text("put me on secondary monitor before clicking me").build();
    btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            dlgStage.showAndWait();
        }
    });
    Button btn2 = ButtonBuilder.create().text("me too").build();
    btn2.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            dlgStage.setX(stage.getX() + stage.getWidth() / 2);
            dlgStage.setY(stage.getY() + stage.getHeight() / 2);
            dlgStage.showAndWait();
        }
    });
    Button btn3 = ButtonBuilder.create().text("me too").build();
    btn3.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            dlgStage.centerOnScreen();
            dlgStage.showAndWait();
        }
    });

    Pane p = FlowPaneBuilder.create().children(btn, btn2, btn3).build();

    Scene scene = SceneBuilder.create().root(p).width(800).height(600).build();
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}
}
```

Drag the stage to a secondary monitor and then click one of the buttons. When you do nothing extra the modal dialog will open on the primary monitor.
What is the easiest way to have the modal dialog open in the center of the parent stage? Stage.centerOnScreen() doesn't same to take into account a dual monitor setup. Should I consider this a bug and file it? Or is there another way to achieve this?

Comment: Would it help to create the dialog on button click? Maybe (not sure) it would take the position of `stage` into account.

Comment: you mean with a setOnMouseClicked handler? Nah, that didn't work

Comment: bummer, should've expected that you tried ;-)

Comment: Only after you suggested it, so thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There a static method

```
static ObservableList<Screen> getScreens() The observable list of currently available Screens.
```

in Screen class. And

```
static Screen getPrimary() The primary Screen.
```

use them to determine, which screen is not a Primary.

You can use it to determine, which screens you have. And use Window. setX and setY methods - to position a window - just a simple math.

Also, I checked in JFX jira, that there are no features about adding any method method centering with a screen as parameter. So, you can file an RFE, to add method centerOnScreen(Screen)...

Comment: Yeah I know about those methods, I could do it manually with them. Although I think a dialog should open in the center of its parent by default. I'll add an issue for that to JIRA.